# WooCommerce - add a product attribute to cart without having to use it as a variable

Tags: variables, attributes, woocommerce

On our store we only sell a product in one color, I have created a "attribute" color that displays on the "additional information" only of the product page, it is not included as a "variable" When added to cart, it will only show what I added on the variable options, which in this case is "sizes"

How can I add an the attribute "color" to the cart without having it used as a variable. Or if it has to be displayed as a variable I don't want it as a drop down.

I am using WooCommerce. Hope I made some sense, sorry I am a designer not a coder.

*!- email removed -!* please post answers to site, not email!!

Answer (score 0):

Make your variable and then use the default selection option to show your item of choice as selected.
Sometimes it makes sense to have them choose, more awareness to what they're buying.